# Nagios Host Downtime Scheduling

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nagios, scheduled-task

Ok, so I've spent a bunch of time on this and I can not seem to get it working in my environment.

I have a Nagios 3.3.1 server with NConf 1.3. All works well and I'm pretty happy.

However, I have a need to schedule host downtime, for various reasons, daily or weekly and wanted to create and cron to handle this.

Easy enough right? I found the following script (customized slightly) and I have been unable to get it to successfully schedule downtime for a host.

http://pastebin.com/MLdebCfR

I'll show an example of the command line to run this script:

```
./nagios_host_downtime.sh hostname '20120417 06:30:00' '20120417 08:30:00' 120 nagiosadmin test
```

In the log file - /usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.log - I see:

```
[1334609909] EXTERNAL COMMAND: SCHEDULE_HOST_DOWNTIME;hostname;1334665800;1334553600;0;0;nagiosadmin;test;
```

However, in the Downtime section of the web console I never see an entry and will still receive alerts during the downtime.

Any one have any thoughts? I might just be screwing up something simple, but I've waste a good amount of time with no joy and just need this to work.

Comment: FYI, there are some serious perfdata-related bugs in 3.3.1. You should consider using 3.2.3 instead. (You tagged this 'ubuntu'... Why aren't you using the packaged nagios?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SCHEDULE_HOST_DOWNTIME;hostname;1334665800;1334553600;0;0;nagiosadmin;test;
>
> [SCHEDULE_HOST_DOWNTIME;host_name;start_time;end_time;fixed;trigger_id;duration;author;comment](http://old.nagios.org/developerinfo/externalcommands/commandinfo.php?command_id=118)

You´re missing `duration`

--

I just tested

> SCHEDULE_HOST_DOWNTIME;host;1334699660;1334699720;1;0;;icingaadmin;comment
>
> SCHEDULE_HOST_DOWNTIME;host;1334699760;1334699920;0;0;120;icingaadmin;comment

What works as expected.

> This host has been scheduled for fixed downtime from 17-04-2012 23:54:20 to 17-04-2012 23:55:20. Notifications for the host will not be sent out during that time period.
>
> This host has been scheduled for flexible downtime starting between 17-04-2012 23:56:00 and 17-04-2012 23:58:40 and lasting for a period of 0 hours and 2 minutes. Notifications for the host will not be sent out during that time period.

Comment: > Ugh, I have been fiddling with the script too much. I have completed a few fixes and I am still unable to see the downtime in the web console. 

> The following is the command line:
> ./nagios_host_downtime.sh idsprodsql02 '20120417 06:30:00' '20120417 08:30:00' nagiosadmin test

> The following is in the log:
> [1334637260] EXTERNAL COMMAND: SCHEDULE_HOST_DOWNTIME;idsprodsql02;1334658600;1334665800;1;0;;nagiosadmin;test

> Yet I still do not have an entry in the log file.

> Thanks for helping me through this.

Comment: Then it should work... Make sure external commands are allowed `check_external_commands=1` (but when they are in the log i assume they've been read), bypass the `./nagios_host_downtime.sh` with a direct `echo "[1234] HOST.." >> PATH/nagios.cmd`, try submitting a passive check/restart and see what happens, and check [`debug_level`](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configmain.html#debug_level) && [`debug_file`](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configmain.html#debug_file)